# Save a Windows system image on the same drive as the one you're imaging?

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk-image

If I don't have any external drives, can I still create a full system image? Can I create a separate partition, and image only the original partition, to be stored on the second partition? Or does it need to image the entire drive?

Comment: Most imaging software allows you to pick the partition(s) you wish to image, no you cannot image the same partition you are actively storing the image on.

Comment: I don't want to store it on the same partition, but on a different partition on the same drive.

Comment: It should work but will be slow since it is using the same physical disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would really depend upon the amount of remaining disk space you have and the software you are using. Some imaging programs will image data+free space. Others won't. I would tentatively say you can make a disk image to another partition on the same hard drive, if the imaging software supports it. If you plan on keeping the image on the separate partition as a backup, be advised that should the hard drive go you will potentially lose both your system and your backup.

Comment: Yeah, it's really just a temporary solution until the new external HDD arrives in a couple days. But you don't know what software I can use to do this?

Comment: Norton Ghost should work. Partimage or Clonezilla should also do what you need.